# Cannot find * in scope

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm migrating objective C to swift. I'm getting the error `Cannot find 'NSUtils' in scope` in the line-

```
_idInstance = NSUtils.sha256(_idInstance)
```

I have the NSUtils class in objective C. The function is also mentioned there and it's working well with other .m files:

```
+ (NSString *)sha256:(NSString *)clear {
        ....
}
```

The autofill suggestions also don't show for this. Please help.

Comment: `NSUtils` - now that's a class that I didn't know Cocoa had :) Unless someone used the `NS` prefix in an incorrect manner...

Answer (score -2):

In Swift, you should really use CryptoKit instead:

```
import CryptoKit

let digest = SHA256.hash(data: myData)
let digestString = String(bytes: digest.map { $0 }, encoding: .ascii)!
```

Comment: there is a manual class that I want to use instead of the module.